# kernel streaming dma: вопрос о работе DMA под ARM64

Tags: linux

Написал драйвер для приема данных с DMA (NW на FPGA) в режиме streaming.

Задача такая, чтобы данные писались в буфер, расположенный в user memory. Приоложение выделяет буфер (malloc) и при помощи ioclt отправляет его адрес в драйвер. Там буфер делится на дескрипторы и каждый дескриптор пишет в dma физический адрес памяти, полученный от dma_map_single.

На x64/x86 все идеально работает, а вот на ARM64 буфер не обновляется. Размер данных приходит верный, а значения в буфере остаются нетронутыми. Как будто DMA не пишет вовсе или не обновлен cache.

Ядро 4.18.16, проверку dma_mapping_error делаю, ошибок нет. Пытаюсь понять, что делаю не так.

Comment: что тут сказать? где-то в драйвере есть что-то системно-зависимое... ну или какая-то аппаратная неисправность... в общем [mcve] в студию...

Comment: DMA sync API забыли. В ARM, в отличие от x86, кэш не когеретный, поэтому надо после каждой операции передачи данных синхронизировать кэш. Подробнее здесь: https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/DMA-API-HOWTO.txt, начиная с *Using Streaming DMA mappings*

Comment: dma_sync_single_for_cpu? Нет, не забыл. Что удивительно, если буфер создан в kernel памяти, все работает. А если в user, значения в буфере не меняются. Но нужно именно пользовательский буфер использовать.

Comment: `for_cpu()`, `for_device()` с правильным флагом direction. Проверьте внимательно, на всякий случай. А пользовательская память скорее всего за пределами DMA маски устройства, так что ещё и bounce buffers могут быть. Также посмотрите как реализован интерфейс UIO (там были примеры как раз для буферов для DMA).

Comment: спасибо, маску и направление проверял. Я подозреваю, что оно вообще и не должно работать. Область памяти, выделяемая в user space не обязана быть неразрывной в физической области памяти. DMA API не обязан ее транслировать на физическое пространство. То, что оно работает в х86 это скорее удачное стечение обстоятельств, что память выделилась без разрывов в физической области. Сам по себе dma_map_single имеет баг - он должен проваливать операцию map в user space. Память должна быть выделена в kernel space и транслирована по средствам mmap'инга и никак иначе. Или я вообще не понимаю ничего.

Comment: Сделал буфер в kernel space и mmap в user space. Все работает. Хотелось сделать буфер в user space, но возиться с sg листом будет означать ограничения на размер пакета и производительность в целом, а у меня поджимает - почти 80мб/с ожидается на ARM-е. Всем спасибо за поддержку.